# Use GIT and Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

We want to use Git and Gitlab in our team. So far I just worked with git on my local comuter. My question: Is it possible to use this normal git version in combination with the online repository Gitlab? 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to make it work if your git version must be no earlier than 1.7.10, as explained in the [doc](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#1-packages-dependencies).

Also, note that Gitlab also uses the normal git in the backend. It is merely a web frontend of git.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

On the command line, you need to add a remote source where you can push to and pull from.

To do this, you need to **set up a RSA key for your account**.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Now you need to put that in your Gitlab profile (profile/keys/new)

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Now you need to [add your remote url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSsrG.png)

```
git remote add origin <<remote_url>>
```

You should now be able to push/pull to your GitLab instance.